# nodejs express rest api post displaying undefined

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, body-parser

im currently trying nodejs for the first time and im trying to make a rest api that i can link to my website that uses postgresql to get the data.

> **categories.js** is the file im currently working on, it holds all get and post methods related to the categories table in postgres

Here's the current code in my categories.js:

```
var express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var router = express.Router();
const {Client} = require('pg');
router.use(bodyParser.json());

const client = new Client({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'postgres',
  port: 5432,
  password: 'admin123',
  database: 'postgres'
})

client.connect();




/* GET categories listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  client.query(`select * from categories`, (err, result)=>{
    if(!err){
      res.send(result.rows);
    }
    else console.log(err.message);
  });
  client.end;

});


/* GET category listing by id. */
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  client.query(`select * from categories where id=${req.params.id}`, (err, result)=>{
    if(!err){
      res.send(result.rows);
    }
    else console.log(err.message);
  });
  client.end;
  
});


/* POST category listing by postman. */
router.post('/', (req, res)=> {
  const category = req.body;
  console.log(category)
  let insertQuery = `INSERT INTO categories
                        (name, createdat)
                        VALUES ('${category.name}','${category.createdat}');`

  client.query(insertQuery, (err, result)=>{
      if(!err){
          res.send('Insertion was successful')
      }
      else{ console.log(err.message) }
  })
  client.end;
})




module.exports = router;
```

the problem is, everytime i try to make a post method through postman using this script:

```
{
    "name": "cat2",
    "createdat": "13/05/201"
}
```

it posts an empty item into the database:

```
{"id":12,"name":"undefined","available":true,"createdat":"undefined"}
```

the get methods work normally by the way, but the post method doesn't

here's the categories table in postgres incase that helps

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.categories
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('categories_id_seq'::regclass),
    name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    available boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
    createdat text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT categories_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Comment: When you console.log(category) do you see the data you are expecting? quick FYI express now have express.json() which is based on body-parser so you don't need to bring body-parser in as an extra dependency.

Comment: @HugoDos i put that there so it displays the page content in postman whenever an error occurs

Comment: just to let you know I was just about to comment the most common mistake is not setting the content type to JSON in postman.

Answer (score 0):

well well well, i found what the problem was lmao, and its actually embarassing.

well basically in the postman program, when i was inputing my data for it to be submitted to the database as json, i had the body selected in text form instead of json, which is why it couldnt recognize my data, cs it was in txt not json..

here's a pic incase someone does a stupid like i did

fix
[image: like this]

mistake
[image: not like this]

Comment: Setting the content type to JSON makes sure the header Content-Type: "application/json" is sent with the request informing the middleware .json() to parse the information as JSON. More information: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json